# How to determine areas of an image using OnTouchListeners

Tags: android, animation, ontouchlistener

I want to know how i can determine the areas A,B,C and D, using the OnTouchListener because i wan to do a specific animation for each letter of the image.

Image:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-y3RJtuieSxo/VNTQIAMNrfI/AAAAAAAAA8w/Lyl_p9IjSQE/s1600/anim3.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the events and then depending on coordinates x, y you got from the click, Example: (public class joc extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //if(this.canvasView.isShown().isFocused().hasFocus()){
    downx = event.getX();
    downy = event.getY();
    int height = canvasView.getHeight();
    int width = canvasView.getWidth();
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //tirar dados
            if ((downy < (height*2/3)) && (downy > (height/3)) && downx > temany_llarg && downx < width-temany_llarg){
                int[] a = canvasView.tirada(V1,V2);
                player[0].dice(a[0], a[1]);
                canvasView.postInvalidate();
            }
            else if (downy > height/2-7*temany_curt-1 && downy < height/2+6*temany_curt+1){
                //if dentro del tamaño del tablero, significa vineta 100 seguro TODO
                id = casilla.getId((int)downx, (int)downy);
                vineta.idCasilla = id;
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-2, width*2/3, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                vineta.setLayoutParams(params);
                vineta.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vineta.requestFocus();
                vineta.bringToFront();
            }
            return true;
```

This is a little example from my code, but u can take it into ur code

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = event.getX();
            int width = view.getWidth();
            int y = event.getY();
            int height = view.getHeight();
            //more code here!
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You can use code like this to get the coordinates of the touch. Once you have the x and y coordinates you can use [arctan2](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) to calculate the angle from the horizontal axis to the point and use that to determine the sector of the image that was pressed.